# update the column value which is a primary key

Tags: postgresql

i want to update the category table here. in jsp 
the code is like below:

```
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE category SET description = ? where  categoryname = ?");
pstmt.setString(1, request.getParameter("description"));
pstmt.setString(2, request.getParameter("categoryname"));
```

while if using this way i can only change the description value not the categoryname value.
the table is here:

```
CREATE TABLE category
(
  categoryname character varying NOT NULL,
  description character varying,
  CONSTRAINT category_pkey PRIMARY KEY (categoryname)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE category
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

i am wondering if i can change the categoryname column value too. how to change jsp code?
the categoryname is primary key because product table has foreign key referencing here.
Thanks.

Comment: Generally, it is a bad idea to use a (var)char column as the PK. In most cases a "surrogate" integer PK (or SERIAL) is added , and a unique constraint is applied to the varchar categoryname column. This will also "reduce" other tables with FKs to this table to use integer fields only, when referring to the category table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change the categoryname column value, but be careful. Your query may be fail if you update this field with a value that is already present.

As Joop has said, the best practice is add an additional field which serves as primary key and this field have any relations with business data.

Your new database structure may be look like this :

```
CREATE TABLE category
(
  id serial not null,
  categoryname character varying NOT NULL,
  description character varying,
  CONSTRAINT category_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE category
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

And of course foreign keys must reference 'id' and not 'categoryname'